# Group 2 variables (age & gender) and find the amount

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Given below data frame

```
Age Gender  Amount
55  M   100
30  F   200
35  M   300
50  M   560
58  F   321
60  F   121
```

Group age in seq(30,60,by=5)

Output should be

```
(30,35) F   200
(50,55) M   560
(55,60) M   100
(55,60) F   442
```

Comment: Please add your code and what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code request forum! If you encountered errors, show them here!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(Age = c(55, 30, 35, 50, 58, 60), Gender = c("M", "F", "M", "M","F","F"), Amount = c(100, 200, 300, 560, 321, 121))

df %>% mutate(Age.new = cut(Age, seq(30, 60, 5), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% group_by(Age.new, Gender) %>% summarise(sum(Amount))
```